# Python - Using os.rename to rename and move a file, but last one in the FOR throws a file in use error

Tags: python

I have some code that runs through a csv of internal codes and renames some jpgs with the looked up external code from the csv, then moves said images into grouped folders. I'm pretty new to Python, goes without saying.

Code works fine - apart from the very last image in the folder, which throws out the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\ImageRename\testresolution.py", line 74, in <module>
    os.rename(oldPath,newPath)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\ImageRename\\Images\\11D003-003_3.jpg' -> 'C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\ImageRename\\Processed\\11D003-003\\15243_3.jpg'
```

If I add more images to the folder, the jpg that was having the issue now works fine, but the new last image throws the error.

Here's the code. (Note - there's some stuff above this that is unrelated that checks image dimensions first that all seems to be working ok. Will post that code too if anyone thinks it could be conflicting somehow). Thanks in advance!

````
# importing the module
import os
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import csv

path= r"C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\ImageRename\Images"  
allfiles = os.listdir(path)

# some other stuff in here I've omitted as I don't think it's relevant


if countbad > 0:
    x = input("There are errors in images. Continue Anyway? Y/N")
    if x == "Y":
        myfile  = open('codes.csv')
        reader = csv.reader(myfile)
        
        processedpath=r"C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\ImageRename\Processed"
        
        rownum = 0
        for row in reader:
            if rownum == 0:
                header = row
            else:
               sku = row[0]
               thgid = row[1]
               imgnumber = 1
               while imgnumber < 9:
                oldPath=os.path.join(path,sku+"_"+str(imgnumber)+".jpg")
                if os.path.exists(oldPath):
                    newPath=os.path.join(processedpath,sku,thgid+"_"+str(imgnumber)+".jpg") 
                    newDir=os.path.join(processedpath,sku)
                    os.makedirs(newDir, exist_ok=True)
                    os.rename(oldPath, newPath)
                imgnumber += 1
            rownum += 1
        myfile.close()```
````

Comment: Does the omitted code do anything with the files? Is it possible that that might somehow leave a file open? (Off-topic note: you may want to use `for (rownum, row) in enumerate(reader):...` to avoid having to keep track of the rownum manually, and similarly `for imgnumber in range(1, 9): ...` )

Comment: Thanks for the reply...well, turns out I am a numpty. I had missed an close line, as indeed the code before opened the image. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous part of my code dealt with checking the size and resolution of the images. Turned out I had missed a line within this code, which was keeping the last file open, which then broke the lines later on.

Added in: img.close() (where img is the variable holding the file), and all now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message carefully, it clearly tells you what the problem is. Python can't open your image because it is already open in another program.

This problem often occurs because the file is open in File Explorer.

To fix this, identify & kill the process which is accessing the image. If you don't know how to do that, just try restarting your computer and run your Python script again - that should fix the problem.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply! I should have said that the image is not open anywhere, and as far as I can see, there isn't a process that should be accessing it. Restarted and I still get the issue.

Comment: @Turtle_Python I see that you have answered your own question - please mark your answer as accepted, so that it will be helpful to anyone who sees this in the future.